# Async Bridge (nuget package) and .NET 4.5.1

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, nuget-package

I just have a problem with one project in C#.. Problem is with transform from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5.1 with nuget package Async Bridge (at 3.5 nuget working correctly).. After re-targeting project there are errors:

```
Error   1152    The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>' exists in both 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\mscorlib.dll' and 'C:\PROJECT.NET\packages\TaskParallelLibrary.1.0.2856.0\lib\Net35\System.Threading.dll'
```

So I removed Async Bridge from project as duplicate .dll library. Because of dll was located in nuget package and in .NET 4.5.1 as default too. After this step I got new errors:

```
Error   1135    The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Threading, Version=1.0.2856.102, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

After some investigation, problem is that in .NET framework 3.5 there wasn't async functionality.. Async Bridge was the solution.. But in .NET framework 4.5.1 was this functionality added and now is my project tottaly broken.. So my question is - is upgrade my project to 4.5.1 possible in some way? 
Thanks for answers

Comment: remove asyncbridge, make sure you're referencing System.Threading, and then recompile **everything** - should fix it...

Comment: actually, as an aside: if someone rebuilt the AsyncBridge.dll targeting .net 4.5, but **without** the `Task`/`Task<T>` types, but **with** `[assembly:TypeForwardedTo(typeof(Task))]` etc - that should actually fix it too, by automatically re-directing requests for that type. Tricky to use with generics, though, IIRC - but could try `[assembly:TypeForwardedTo(typeof(Task<>))]`

Comment: Thx for advice, I tried your first one post yesterday but unsuccessfuly.. I will try the second now

Comment: may I ask why you want to get this to 4.5.1? I think you could get your lib(?) working with `BindingRedirect`s too - anyway, can you give us some hints where you failed while trying the first (very good) advice?

Comment: Yes, of course.. I only want to upgrade one of my projects of solution from old .net framework.. And I faild trying first advice because of there are others projects in 3.5 and there are references between them..